# LINQ - which layer should LINQ typically fall into, DAL?

Tags: linq, frameworks, data-access-layer

just wanted to gather different ideas and perspectives as to which layer should (and why) LINQ fall into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it depends on what you want to do with linq. when using linq2sql i`d recommend the DAL, but Linq is more than just database access. you can use it to manipulate lists, ienumerables of business objects and so on... Linq itself can be useful everywhere in your application.

Answer (score 5):

LINQ = Language INtegrated Queries. This is the query extensions that allows you to query anything from databases to lists/collections to XML. The query language is useful in any layer.

However, a lot of people refer to LINQ to SQL as just "LINQ". In that context, a combined BLL/DAL makes sense when you're using L2S and that's where you do LINQ queries against your database. That does of course not exclude doing subsequent queries against the results from those same queries in new (Linq to objects) queries in higher layers...

Answer (score 3):

I consider your DataContext-derived object to your DAL layer itself, and LINQ is just a very flexible interface to it.   Hence I use LINQ queries directly in the Business layer.

Answer (score 1):

Both.  DataContext is the DAL and, when using the designer, the auto-generated partial classes that map on to SQL objects (tables,views) can be considered part of your business layer.  I implement partial classes that implement some of the partial methods to enforce validation and security as needed.  Some business rules don't map directly on to DB objects and are handled via other classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are doing Linq to Sql, you should always do it in your DAL. However if you are doing Linq to Objects where you are just filtering, playing with different object you can do that is BL layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think LINQ should be the very lower-level (DAL) and I think it should be wrapped into a BLL.

I know a lot of people like to use the partial accessibility of the models that LINQ to SQL generates but I think you should have clear separation of interests (see what I did there?).  I think if you're going to have business logic it needs to be decoupled completely from your data access logic.

I think what makes it tricky is the fact that you can keep chaining those LINQ extension methods anywhere you have a using System.Linq line in your code.  Again though I think LINQ belongs with the definition and should be at the lowest possible level.  It also makes TDD/Unit Testing much, much easier when you wrap the usage of LINQ in a BLL.

Answer (score 0):

I use linq in the traditional 'data access layer' or in 'data access objects'.  This allows modularization of code, promotes data code in one place (vs cutting and pasting the same code a few different places) and allows a different front end to be developed with relative ease.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the architecture of your application, and it makes a huge difference how much the presentation model matches the data model. I agree with separating out business logic operations from the data objects and access methods created by LINQ. I also tend to wrap all data-level operations inside a manager class so I can make the data context an internal class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point of Linq is that it replaces your DAL.

The equivalent to your old DAL is all the auto-generated code behinf the DBML files + anything extra that Linq can't do added by you.